# Ubuntu OS changed to elementry OS 0.4 Loki

Tags: unity, elementary, elementary-theme

My current OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I, out of curiosity, installed Elementary Desktop. And then I removed it and got back to Unity.

I installed it using following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop`
```

and removed it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge elementary-desktop && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now after reverting back to Unity, when I checked my OS, its still changed to elementary OS.

Following is the text from hardinfo app:

```
-Version-
Kernel         : Linux 4.4.0-45-generic (i686)
Compiled        : #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:05 UTC 2016
C Library       : Unknown
Default C Compiler      : GNU C Compiler version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 
Distribution        : elementary OS 0.4 Loki
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, I think this question is a duplicate of that linked question. If you don't agree, please edit your question saying what didn't work.

Comment: @Anwar removing them via ppa-purge, as in you answer, show me 404 Not Found error

Comment: I had removed the ppa's manually and I added them again to remove them again via ppa-purge, as in your answer

Comment: If you're getting 404 error for some ppa, remove those PPA entry using `sudo apt-add-repository -r <ppa-name>` format

Comment: okay, I removed all the ppas via apt-add-repository. Will this remove the elementary effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47645/discussion-between-kush-grover-and-anwar).